# Custom library directory for TypeScript

Tags: typescript, module, node-modules, libraries

Recently, I've been working quite a bit with some more advanced TypeScript features and was wondering if there was a way to define a custom path for libraries, so that the compiler can locate and use them, yet doesn't include them in the output. I've managed something similar before by defining `typeRoots` but this is exclusively for definitions files and any attempt to import source files results in the library not being found.

Currently my client's `tsconfig.json` looks like this

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["ESNext"],
        "rootDir": "lily",
        "baseUrl": "/usr/lib/tslibs",
        "typeRoots": ["/usr/lib/tslibs"],
        "types": ["globals"]
    }
}
```

My only problem with this is that TypeScript complains that `/usr/lib/tslibs` is outside of the `rootDir`. Which may be true, but if I define a structure similar to this, instead using the `node_modules` folder for libraries, I don't get this issue.

I also noticed that including `moduleResolution": "classic"` changed the error to simply cannot find the library. I'm wondering if there's a way to achieve this, preferably with as little configuration on the client's side as possible as the clients should be able to avoid defining this.

Thansk

Comment: Split up your project and use the project references feature

Comment: This is awesome, thanks so much. Is there a way I can make all items within a directory become references?

Comment: Here's the documentation for the project references feature. Check it out: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html